# Tabs are not visible in sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

For some reason, I do not see tabs (filename).

[image]

I have tried `Show Tabs` option under View Menu section, but nothing happens. I have even tried reinstalling but still the same issue.

I even tried to look in console for any errors but nothing was logged.

Can you kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: So when you hit Ctrl+N nothing happens ? Or Ctrl+T ?

Comment: @Devid it opens new tab but still tabs are missing.

Comment: Do you have any non-standard theme installed?

Comment: I have Brogrammer and Numix installed. Can they cause any issues?

Comment: DId you registered your copy ?

Comment: No. Its an unregistered copy.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Question rolled back to remove answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks! Have moved it to an answer. Will not mark it as answer but have added as a reference.

Comment: @Rajesh There is nothing wrong with marking it as the answer. I think you have to wait 48 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a package [SidebarSeparator](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SidebarSeparator) that was causing issues.

Have removed it and its working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of suggesting something *too* obvious: you can show/hide tabs from the View menu.

[image]

Comment: I have already mentioned in question that I have tried it but no success.

Comment: What are those icons in the window-bar on your right? Could they be from a package that's conflicting with Brogrammer? Try disabling it. Repeat for other packages that apply visual changes.

Comment: Thats a title bar and icons are system apps. Nothing related to sublime. Still I'll try removing themes.

Comment: Fixed my issue. I'm used to using keyboard to go through menu and enable or disable word wrap and must have disabled tabs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem

I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> shortcuts
and I searched `view: toggle menu` that show/hide menu.